# How to get a list of two words before or after a keyword in python?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I collected this data and I am trying to identify if the keyword exact what are the two word before it and after it

data = pd.read_csv( 'jobs.csv')

view(data)

| Job | Discerption |
| --- | --- |
| Engineer | the job requires x,y,z..... |
| Driver | this job need a high-school and Communication skills |

The data length is about 10k

For example the keyword "Communication"
Can i find the words before and after Communication and make the results look like this

| Job | Discerption | after | before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Engineer | the job requires x,y,z | NA | NA |
| Driver | this job need a high-school and Communication skills | skills | high-school, and |

Na because the keyword doesn't exist

I tired pandas and regex but nothing is working for me :/

I would really appreciate the help

Comment: Are you looking just in the `description` column? Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Just to be clear, your issue is that you're looking for "communication" but it was misspelled as "commination"?

Comment: @Stef Correct communication I fixed it.

Comment: @FullyBuzzwordCompliant I am looking only in the description column

Comment: @Abe well, in that case, I have no idea what the sentence *"Na because the keyword doesn't exist"* means.

Comment: PS COuld you please include your dataframe as an easily reproducible example? For instance, replace `data = pd.read_csv( 'jobs.csv')` with `data = pd.DataFrame({'Job': ['Engineer', 'Driver'], 'Description': [...], ...})`. This way it's much easier for people who might have an answer to experiment with your data and write their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map a column into another column by applying a function to every element.

If an element is a list of words, you can use `list.index` to find the position of the keyword you're looking for, then list slicing `sentence[i-2:i]` to get the two words before a given index.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Job': ['Engineer', 'Driver'],
    'Description': ['the job requires x,y,z', 'this job need a high-school and Communication skills']
})

def get_two_words_before(sentence, word):
    sentence = sentence.split()
    if word in sentence:
        i = sentence.index(word)
        return sentence[i-2:i]
    else:
        return []

def get_two_words_after(sentence, word):
    sentence = sentence.split()
    if word in sentence:
        i = sentence.index(word)
        return sentence[i+1:i+3]
    else:
        return []

data['before'] = data['Description'].map(lambda x: get_two_words_before(x, 'Communication'))

data['after'] = data['Description'].map(lambda x: get_two_words_after(x, 'Communication'))

print(data)
```

Output:

```py
        Job             Description              before     after
0  Engineer  the job requires x,y,z                  []        []
1    Driver  this job need a hig...  [high-school, and]  [skills]
```